# How to achieve a producer-product relationship

Tags: java, data-structures, one-to-many

I am trying to create a one to many relationship using two classes - `Producer` and `Product`. The relationship between classes is simple:

> A producer produces many products, each product is produced by a single producer.

The class structure is like this:

```
public class Producer{
    private int producerID;
    private String producerName;
    private String producerAddress;
    // private ArrayList<Product> products;    // shall I do this?
}

public class Product{
    private int productID;
    private String productName;
    // private int producerID;                 // or shall I do this instead?
}
```

I was wondering how can I create such a relationship using these classes. Shall I just hold `producerID` as a property of the `Product` class, or shall I create a list of `Product`s and every time I create a product, just add it to product list in the `Producer` class?

In terms of databases, it is a simple relationship, but how can I achieve this in Java?

Can you please shed some light on pros and cons of both approaches?

Comment: Why not make Product hold an instance of Producer instead?

Comment: Are you trying to map your Java objects to the database entities?

Comment: @BheshGurung No, just modeling classes. Not mapping objects using Hibernate or JPA.

Comment: @gtgaxiola indeed, explains a has-a relationship. However, the main question still remains, which one is better? A producer holding a list of products, or a product holding a reference to a producer object?

Answer (score 3):

From my perspective, there is nothing bad with doing both, it gives you a little more ease of access.

Consider if you just have the producerID on the Product.  If you had a Producer and wanted to know what Products he produces, you'd have to go through each Product and check....inefficient.

Now consider if you have an ArrayList of product on the producer class.  If you have a Product, and you want to know its producer, you have to query each producer and see if its in the list.  Inefficient.

If you have both, it gives you the best of both worlds (though if your products are non-unique, you might want an arraylist of IDs as well, to show you can have multiple producers per product).

SAMPLE CODE AS REQUESTED:

I would start with these classes:

```
public class Producer{

    private int producerID;
    private String producerName;
    private String producerAddress;
    private ArrayList<Product> products;   
}


public class Product{
    private int productID;
    private String productName;
    private Producer productProducer;
}
```

probably add methods like this for the Product

```
public Boolean isProducer (Producer testProducer){
    if (this.productProducer.getId() == testProducer.getId())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and this for the producer:

```
public Boolean produces(Product testProduct){
    if (this.products.contains(testProduct))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Then for the producer you can add methods like:

```
public Product getProductById (int Id){
    return this.products.get(Id)
}
```

To add a new Product I would do something like (FarmerJoe is an existing Producer)

```
new Product apples = new Product();

apples.setProducer(FarmerJoe);
FarmerJoe.addProduct(apples);
```

the set Producer method would be simple:

```
public void setProducer(Producer owner){
    this.Producer = owner;
}
```

so would the addProduct:

```
public void addProduct(Product newProduct){
    products.add(newProduct);
}
```

obviously you can doll all of this up a lot, very simple example.

Comment: Products are unique, hence, just an ID would work. Can you elaborate on "best of both worlds" part please. I can think of an Association class as one option for what you are suggesting, however, I am not looking for a many-many relationship.

Comment: @AndrewLobley literally instead of doing one or the other you do both

Comment: Isn't this going to create a cyclic relationship?

Comment: its just a one to many relationship.  The many know who their one is and the one knows who their many is.  Not cyclic at all

Comment: Can I burden you with a request to provide a code snippet? I am trying to store it like this:
In Producer - private ArrayList<Product> product;
In Product - private Producer producer;